# Laravel 5.6 Validation Array Data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When validating a request data, we are getting the result filtered out by the rules. For example, the following request:

```
$this->post(route('test'), [
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'john' => 'doe'
]);
```

And in my controller, I have the following:

```
$data = request()->validate([
    'foo' => 'required|string'
]);
```

Then if I perform a `dd($data);`, I would get the following:

```
array:1 [
  "foo" => "bar"
]
```

So far so good. However, when working with arrays, for example, the following request:

```
$this->post(route('test'), [
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'names' => [
        'en' => 'Product',
        'fr' => 'Produit',
        'john' => 'Doe'
    ]
]);
```

And then in my controller, I have the following:

```
$data = request()->validate([
    'foo' => 'required|string',
    'names' => 'array',
    'names.en' => 'required|string',
    'names.fr' => 'required|string'
]);
```

It would return the following `$data`:

```
array:2 [
  "foo" => "bar"
  "names" => array:3 [
    "en" => "Product"
    "fr" => "Produit"
    "john" => "doe"
  ]
]
```

Now my questions are:

1. Why is `'john' => 'doe'` in my `names` key when I don't have it in my validation rules?
2. Is there a way to remove unspecified array keys from the data?

### Update

I've tested the suggestion of @JonasStaudenmeir, however the result is not what I expected.

Request:

```
$this->post(route('test'), [
    'names' => [
        'en' => 'Doe',
        'fr' => 'John'
    ]
]);
```

Controller:

```
$rules = [
    'names' => 'array',
    'names.en' => 'string'
];

dd(request()->only(array_keys($rules));
```

Expected Output:

```
array:1 [
  "names" => array:2 [
    "en" => "Doe"
  ]
]
```

Actual Output:

```
array:1 [
  "names" => array:2 [
    "fr" => "John"
    "en" => "Doe"
  ]
]
```

Comment: can you post the form as well ?

Comment: @Alessandro.Vegna There's no form. It's a request sent from a `TestCase`.

Comment: 1) I imagine the reason is that `names` validates, so the entire array is kept.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but the part where you are calling `$this->post(route('test'), [...])`, it seems you are actually passing `"jonh" => "doe"` as request data?

Comment: Validation does not remove the entries, it just checks if the entries respect the rules. You can remove the unexpected data with unset()

Comment: @Michio Yes exactly I do pass it but look at my first example. If it's not in the validation rules, the data is removed. However, it's not the same for an array.

Comment: @Alessandro.Vegna Look at my first example, when it's not an array, the data is removed automatically.

Comment: @JoelHinz Even if I remove the rule `'names' => 'array'`, the whole array is kept.

Answer (score 0):

For cases with only nested rules (`'names.en'`) but no parent rule (`'names'`),
this will be fixed in 5.7: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/23708

Until then you can use this workaround:

```
$data = request()->only(array_keys($rules));
```

If you do you have a parent rule, this would be much more complicated to achieve.

I would argue that receiving the whole `'names'` array in the validated data can be seen as the expected behavior. The idea is that the validator returns the data for each rule. In your case it returns the data for the `'names' => 'array'` rule, which is the whole `'names'` array.

Comment: I missed the `'names' => 'array'` rule, I updated my answer.